# How to test a loop inside an AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, spy

I'm trying to testing service but i don't know how to test loop inside. Is it possible to test case with host.lenght===1  in different way than mock url that return host.length=1. Do I have to callFake all my code inside service to test it? Also how to test isNaN? 
Here's my code:

```
if (host.length === 1 || !isNaN(host[host.length - 1])) {

     name = a.hostname;

} else {

     if (host[0] === "www") {
          slice = 1;
     }
     name = host.slice(slice, host.length - 1).reverse().join(" ");
}
```

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oe0fhju7/)**

Comment: Hey man, you say you want to test `loop` but I don't see one, are you sure you have posted correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it looks simplest to just use a URL that will give you this behaviour. In my opinion, this will also be a better test as it will actually test the intent of the code, rather than just ensuring that certain methods are called. After all, this code was written to cope with different types of URL, why not test them with exactly that?

You already have a test for this url: `'http://angular.com/about'`. For the case you are talking about, you could use `'http://angular/about'` and then `'http://www.angular.com/about'` to test the code that strips out the `www.` part.